# SQL Server bulk insert and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can we use parameters instead of text file in bulk insert into SQL Server?

I want to pass the values by parameters to stored procedure, and if the procedure founds any data in the table , then it should replace the old record with the new record.

For example if I have a Grades table and its have a mark column

if the mark column contain data and the proc pass another data then he should replace the old value by the new value

How can I do all this things?

Thanks

Comment: You should elaborate on your replacement logic.

Comment: Take a look at table valued parameters - you can pass all the data into the sproc and then process in code.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you would write a procedure that performs an UPDATE instead of a BULK INSERT.